# Qt, how to set text edit scroll bar to the bottom? C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt3

I have the text edit box as a chat window, but I was wondering if there was a way to set the scroll bar to be at the bottom to show the most updated message.

I am currently using Qt3 and C++.

chat_box->.... I tried looking and was only able to find "ScrollBarMode" but it only lets me turn it on or off or auto... which doesn't really help.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: why qt3? why not use the latest 4.x release? (I suppose you could be working on legacy software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scotchi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817048/qt-how-to-set-text-edit-scroll-bar-to-the-bottom-c/1817052#1817052) would be correct if it was Qt4. Qt3 solution would be something like:

```
QScrollBar *v = chat_box->verticalScrollBar();
v->setValue(v->maxValue());
```

I didn't test this code since I don't have Qt3 anymore. Check if it works.

Comment: It works for one time, but then it gets Fatal IO error: client killed.

Not sure why that is happening. But I am refreshing my chat box every time someone sends a message to it.

Answer (score 6):

```
textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(
    textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
```

Put that after the line where you insert text.

Comment: Ahh, damn :(

.ui/../form2.ui.h:37: error: ‘class QScrollBar’ has no member named ‘setSliderPosition’
.ui/../form2.ui.h:37: error: ‘class QScrollBar’ has no member named ‘maximum’

Comment: That was Qt 4; there's probably a Qt 3 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

...if possible (I don't know your environment) please switch to Qt4 - there are so many disadvantages and missing supprt, missing functionality etc. in Qt3.

ciao,
Chris

PS: It's fairly easy to switch to Qt4 - you don't have to rewrite all of your code, because Qt4 has build in Qt3-Support with a converter tool for your sources.